# Why am I unable to sudo past permissions on the “~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync” directory in macOS?

Tags: macos, backup, macbook, iphone, ios

If I run this I get `Operation not permitted`:

```
ls -al  ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
```

This is off limit to safeguard the backup, but it *is* owned by me, hence I *should* be able to run this to find out how much storage `MobileSync` is taking:

```
sudo du -hs  ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
```

But even that fails. Why am I unable to sudo past permissions?

#### Context

After upgrading to a new MacBook Pro, I see that the iPhone (the iPhone remains the same) has its music collection backed-up.

With the old MacBook Pro my music collection was on the main disk.

On the new MacBook Pro, it's on an external disk, but I still want to sync music *from* MB *to* iPhone, and *not* to back-up the music back on MacBook Pro (which would be silly).

Running `sudo` will help in getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: You probably need to give Terminal full disk access. There should be nothing stopping you in your own ~/Library folder. btw, it's quicker to just Get Info on the folder ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin ah.. nice.. I forget that there is sometimes an alternative to the command line (!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open `System Settings...` (from Apple menu; top-left of screen).
- Click on `Privacy & Security` from the left pane.
- Click `Full Disk Access` under `Privacy`.
- Toggle the switch for `Terminal`.